# VS Code does not open (hangs) on Windows 10 pro after recent security update

Tags: visual-studio-code

After the recent update, VS Code no longer opens.  There are 4 threads in Task Manager, but the program does not open, even after waiting a long time.

Comment: thanks for self-answering. please edit the question though to include any relevant log messages from the Output Panel. Questions should include enough information to allow _anyone_ to get to the answer with the right know-how. Currently, you got to the answer with information you have yet to disclose in the question. (Self-answering does not mean you get a free pass on question quality standards). It also removes the risk of future answerers writing answers here for unrelated problems, which is not good for searchability and _focus_ in the knowledge-base.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of failed attempts, I found that the recent update blocks network paths (UNC paths).  In my case, I am using a roaming profile mapped to a network path (`\\vm-file\users\etc`), and apparently there is a security concern.

I was able to resolve it following the instructions in the "**Working with UNC Paths**" section of this page:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/windows#_working-with-unc-paths

Here is the issue:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/182070

You can see more status messages by opening VSCode from the command prompt.  Just open a Command Prompt, navigate to your installation folder, and execute `code`.  This is where I was finally able to get information about why it was hanging.